# why am i facing the CORS Policy problem in .net 4.5.2 while i configered it in my WebAPIConfig class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, cors

i have a project (WebAPI .Net 4.5.2), when i created the APIs and tried to access it from ajax calls and flutter application i got the CORS Policy issue then i tried all the solutions i found in my way but nothing worked

this is my WebAPIConfig

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
        {
            public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
            {

            config.EnableCors();

            var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"); 
            config.EnableCors(corsAttr);

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
                config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
            }
        }
```

and i tried to send the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" from the ajax (headers) but still facing the same problem with the error "Access to "XMLHttpRequest at (http://192.68.1.46/EmpPenalitiesAPI/api/FollowUpImage/GetPenalities) from origin (https://localhost:44380) has been blocked by CORS Policy"

also i tried to put this line above my controller and its methods
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

but nothing changed. so i would be thankful if someone helped me.

Comment: Might be http to https.